# Temperature, Kinetic Energy, and Chemical Potential

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, chemical-potential

I have a confusion that in an Homogeneous electron gas.

When $T=0$, we know that $\mu=E_F$.

So Kinetic Energy per electron=$\frac{3}{5}E_F=\frac{3}{5}\mu$.

I thought that Temperature is related to kinetic energy. How can $T=0$ condition can have kinetic energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you say is a quantum mechanical problem. Electron gas model quantised the energy level, and Pauli exclusive principle told us fermions can't condesate to k＝0 state all.  T＝0 gives step-function-like distribution of fermions so obviously they have kinetic energy to quantum view.